# SQL loop problem

Tags: .net, sql, report, while-loop

I have a problem, I hope somebody out there can help.
I'm not really good at sql programming so I need help from u guys.

Here's my problem, I have customercode that has possible of 2 or 3 addresses.
sample:

```
cust1  address1
cust1  address2
cust1  address3
cust2  address1
cust2  address2
```

I want to generate a report in .net to be like this:

```
cust1  address1  address2  address3
cust2  address1  address2
```

Can somebody help?

Comment: Sounds like a pivot query, but it'd be nice to have a sample of data and an expected output based on that data.  How do you know which address is first/second/third/etc and what database is this for?

Comment: If you post code, XML, or fixed table structures, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! No need for messy &nbsp; markup stuff.....

Answer (score 1):

This assumes 2 tables:

```
 select 
    custName, A1.Address + ' ' + A2.Address + ' ' + A3.Address
 from
    Customers as C
    inner join Address as A1 on A1.CustKey = C.CustKey
    inner join Address as A2 on A2.CustKey = C.CustKey and A1.AddressKey <> A2.Addresskey
    left join Address as A3 on A3.CustKey = C.CustKey and A3.AddressKey <> A1.AddressKey and A3.AddressKey <> A2.AddressKey
```

Edit to show:

This assumes 1 table:

```
 select 
    A1.Customer, 
    A1.Address + ' ' + A2.Address + ' ' + A3.Address
 from
    Customer as A1 
    inner join Customer as A2 on A2.CustKey = A.CustKey and A1.Address <> A2.Address 
    left join Customer as A3 on A3.CustKey = A.CustKey and A3.Address <> A1.Address and A3.Address <> A2.Address
```